# Selenium: Select 2nd item by both class and with certain text?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, c#, selenium-ide

I am creating some test scripts using Selenium WebDriver in C#. The AUT contains a left menu in which the position/ordering of the links depend upon the 'User Preferences' and a lot of factors/configuration from Admin and user side, so XPath is not an option for me.

I used IDE for recording the same and then generating the code, but by default IDE also used XPath, so I added some commands by myself in recorded script and tried to find the element, with the 'Find' button provided in Selenium IDE. After a couple of tries it worked in IDE, i.e. IDE highlighted the element which I want to find, but when I copied the same code in VSTS it is not working.

This is the code generated by IDE, I am not able to get the reason why this is working in IDE and not in VSTS code, I haven't seen any other command to show such a behavior.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span:contains(Issues Management)")).Click();
```

This code throws element not found/similar error when executed in WebDriver but works fine in IDE. I have seen a similar post over [SQAForums](http://www.sqaforums.com/forums/selenium/152218-css-selector-works-ide-but-not-webdriver.html), but that too doesn't explain it's reason well. I am using Firefox as a browser for creating these tests.

HTML of the element is:

```
<a class="rpLink rpExpandable" title="MyServices" href="#">
<span class="rpOut">
<span class="rpExpandHandle"></span>
<span class="rpText">
Issues Management
<span class="menuItemRole">Container menu item</span>
</span>
</span>
</a>
```

The complexity is there can be multiple elements with the same text 'Issues Management' on the page, but as far as I know they will be under a different section/class name.

Comment: How about asking a developer to provide static IDs for those links in left menu? There is a great benefit from this as you will always be able to interact with web element no matter what the position of this link compare to others.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use [0] for the first instance

This may be due to the seleniumIDE selecting a first instance by default
You can achieve this manually with:

```
CssSelector("span.rpText:contains(Issues Management)")[0]
```

Also, if the class is unique then use it in the selector, i.e.

css:

```
driver.
  FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.rpText:contains(Issues Management)")).Click();
```

xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(
"/descendant::a[@class='post-rpText'][2]:contains('Issues Management')")).click();
```

Comment: Already mentioned that 'contains' is not working in WebDriver :(

Comment: Actually you didn't specifically mention `contains`, just the code is not working. Also you didn't use the rptText class in your example so my example is different.  Not trying to be annoying, just what I found.

Comment: You are right, that I didn't mentioned this statement, my mistake :). I will try your solution too.

Answer (score 1):

"contains" isn't a valid css selector, so it won't work (see [this CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)).  I read somewhere it was part of a draft version of CSS once, but got cut (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#content-selectors)).

Xpath may still be an option; even if the order of elements on the page is uncertain, you can use a partial xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='rpText' and text()='Issues Management']")).click();
```

You can also chain findElements to narrow things down if that doesn't work for some reason

```
driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("a[title='MyServices']")).findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Issues Management']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below XPath:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Issues Management')]
```

Might be it will help you out.